# Why python eval() can access imported functions, but not classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, eval

I have a module that defines a class and a function:

```
#barbaz.py
class Bar:
    pass

def baz():
    return "hello"
```

In another module, I have a function with an eval statement:

```
#foo.py (version 1)
def foo(baz: callable):
    bazstr: str = baz.__name__
    print(bazstr)
    try:
        f=eval(f'{bazstr}()')
        print(f'result: {f}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"eval error: {e}")
```

And finally, I have a test in another module:

```
#test.py
from evalf import foo
from barbaz import baz, Bar

#This works...
foo(baz)
#This doesn't
foo(Bar)
```

The `baz` works, but the `Bar` doesn't. I get the output:

```
baz
result: hello
Bar
eval error: name 'Bar' is not defined
```

It seems that `eval` cannot use classes that have been imported from a module, unless it is imported directly into the same module as the `foo()` function. i.e, this works:

```
#foo.py (version 2)
from barbaz import Bar

def foo(baz: callable):
    bazstr: str = baz.__name__
    print(bazstr)
    try:
        f=eval(f'{bazstr}()')
        print(f'result: {f}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"eval error: {e}")

foo(Bar)
```

Why does version 2 of `foo.py` work, and version 1 thrown the shown error?

How can I get around this, and use an imported class in an eval statement that lives in it's own module?

Answer (score 2):

`foo.py` doesn't work as expected because it doesn't have *either* the class *or* the function in the global namespace (which is where `eval` looks for names not found in local scope). It works on the function because, by sheer coincidence, the outside function (`baz`) and name of the parameter (`baz`) are the same. It didn't see the `def baz` function at all, it saw the parameter you named (coincidentally) `baz`.

The solution is to just use the name of the *parameter* you received unconditionally; if you must use `eval`, just hardcode the name of the callable in it to `baz`, because that's *always* what it's called in your local scope. You probably shouldn't use `eval` (in your code, `f = baz()` would do the job just fine), but if you must, that's the solution.

Comment: >`foo.py doesn't work as expected because it doesn't have either the class or the function in the global namespace`. Is it possible to add a function or class to the global namespace? Alternatively, can I manually pass it into the `eval` namespace with the seccond argument, i.e something like `eval("code", {'Baz' : Baz})`

Comment: @CraigHickman: You definitely don't want `foo` polluting its own global namespace on every call just to do this. If `eval` is an absolute *must*, you can explicitly pass `dict`s for the `globals` and `locals` arguments to `eval` that will let you make whatever names you like available in the scope of the `eval` (make sure you include whatever stuff from actual globals/locals you rely on too). The insistence on `eval` [smells of an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040), given the lack of need for it in the code provided, but yes, that's how you'd do it if you needed to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `baz` in your `foo` function, and no `Bar`.

```
def foo(baz: callable):
    bazstr: str = baz.__name__
    print(bazstr)
    try:
        f = eval(f'{bazstr}()')
        print(f'result: {f}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"eval error: {e}")
```

Using [`eval` is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/13552470), you can simply add `()` beside the callable parameter. I placed the code from your three files into one, as the separate files doesn't change what it does:

```
class Bar:
    pass

def baz():
    return "hello"

def foo(baz: callable):
    try:
        f = baz()
        print(f'result: {f}')
    except Exception as e:
        print("Not callable.")

foo(baz)
foo(Bar)
```

Output:

```
result: hello
result: <__main__.Bar object at 0x0000020EA3496E48>
```

Comment: >`The problem is that you have baz in your foo function, and no Bar.`

That's just the name of the function parameter. I've eddited it to make it clearer

Comment: >`Using eval is dangerous`. I know, but in this case I really need it. The example in the question is just a minimal representation of the problem.

Comment: @CraigHickman: No, it's not "just the name of the parameter"; it's critical to why one call worked and the other didn't. *Neither* version of your call works when you change the parameter name to `bar` (because now neither `baz` nor `Bar` is visible in either local or global scope). Your edited code no longer reproduces the behavior you claim to see (and it's still got a typo; you claim it's `foo.py`, but you import from `evalf`).